# Apple Mail make mails unsigned by default

Tags: mail.app

I have lost patience with outlook and have started using apple mail with my corporate exchange account.

A problem is that every mail I send by default picks up an ios developer certificate that i have associated with this e-mial address.
I know you can click on the button on each mail to turn off signing that message, but i'd like the default to be NOT to sign each message i create.
J

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Go to your your Preferences of the Mail application. Then, you should be in the Account section. Choose your account then at the very bottom change TLS Certificate to "None".